# program custom wordpress plugin to output only to a specific page

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to know how to take the output of a custom built Wordpress plugin and output it onto a specific page.

I know that I need to use the add_action() / add_filter() functions to call the function which outputs the plugins output when a wordpress hook function runs.

Currently I am using the 'the_content' hook.
This outputs my plugins output to all pages in my theme which call the the_content() function.

Which hook can I use to make the output only appear on a specific page.
Also
It would be useful to know how to create a page using my plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [`is_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page)

```
if (is_page(123)) {
  // put your hooks here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put your code in a file inside plugin directory
then
use this

```
   function page_directory()
{
    if(is_page('123')){   
        $dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
        include($dir."custom/page.php");
        die();
    }
}

add_action( 'wp', 'page_directory' );
```